# Hive sentence CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW permissions

Tags: hive, view, permissions

My question is what do this sentences when exists the view.

It performs an ALTER VIEW (that don't change the permissions)

Or it performs a DROP and a CREATE (that makes that other users lost his permissions on the view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create or replace` is equivalent to `drop and create`. (You can refer to this jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1078).
So, permissions may get reset.

Hive permission on table can be controlled but i am not sure about views. But from my oracle background, i can say there may be problems.

Comment: That's not really how it works. 
Permissions can be given to objects like tables of views, not to the entire database.
So, if you has read permissions on a viee, and the owner drop the view, and create a nee view with the same name, you don't have permissions to the new view.
If the owner make an ALTER VIEW you don't loose any permission.
So, my question is, the REPLACE of the CREATE or REPLACE, make an ALTER VIEW or a DROP and CREATE VIEW?

Comment: create or replace is equivalent to drop and create(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1078). So, permissions may get reset.

Comment: I agree, i modified my answer